# The variables are initializing when I'm using inheritance between two classes

Tags: class, oop, object, initialization, shapes

this is the code I wrote:

```
public class shapess
{
    public int len1, len2, len3;
    public void SetVars (int Len1, int Len2, int Len3)
    {
        len1 = Len1;
        len2 = Len2;
        len3 = Len3;
    }
}
public class triangle : shapess
{
    shapess sh = new shapess();
    public void Perimeter()
    {
        sh.SetVars(3, 6, 9);
        int peri = len1 + len2 + len3;
        Console.WriteLine("The perimeter is: "+peri);
    }
}
```

When I tried to play this by using `triangle tr = new triangle(); tr.Perimeter();` it showed me that my variables (len1, len2 & len3) equal to 0 and the output was: `The perimeter is: 0`.
What is my problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `Shapess` instance inside `Trangle` class and set that instance's len1,len2 .. not the values of the Trangle itself len1,len2.... Try

```
public class triangle : shapess
{
    public void Perimeter()
    {
        SetVars(3, 6, 9);
        int peri = len1 + len2 + len3;
        Console.WriteLine("The perimeter is: "+peri);
    }
}
```